# Bad Request - ERROR 3840: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format when using a Sign In policy

Tags: adal

Issue logged here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/537

Guidance is to ask here.

I am finding both Sign Up and Sign In policies fail with a BadRequest 400:

```
2016-02-24 17:48:30.047 Microsoft Tasks for Consumers[8167:232019] -[ADAuthenticationBroker webAuthenticationDidCompleteWithURL:][408][main] 
 2016-02-24 17:48:31.275 Microsoft Tasks for Consumers[8167:232077] ADALiOS [2016-02-24 20:48:31 - 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] ERROR: JSON deserialization. Additional Information: Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}. Body text: 'Bad Request'. HTTPS Code: 400. Response correlation id: (null). ErrorCode: 3840.
 2016-02-24 17:48:31.287 Microsoft Tasks for Consumers[8167:232077] ADALiOS [2016-02-24 20:48:31 - 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] ERROR: Error raised: 3840. Additional Information: Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain Details: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.. ErrorCode: 3840.
```

Images copied from issues post:
[Screen shot of error occurring in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSUdz.png)

Some additional notes:

Last week, for Sign Up, if I chose "Run Now" from the policy blade, the policy runs to completion, and I can see the correct details, including a Display Name in the Azure management portal users table.

This week, when I do the same, the display name always appears in the Azure AD users table as "unknown". I am not sure if its related, however, I did not change anything about my applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some thanks to the ADALiOS guys, the issue appeared to be because we were not requesting with the same clientId and scopeId. That did resolve the issue.

Git hub thread here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/537